# Cannot reassign $this variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a cannot reassign $this error message for the public function isUsernameAvailable($this->input->post('username')) line. I've looked over my code and can't locate the cause of why I can't do this. What the function is used for is a post jquery function with json sent to php.

```
public function isUsernameAvailable($username)
{
    if ($this->usersmodel->isUsernameAvailable($username))
    {
        echo '{"username":"found"}';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '{"username":"notfound"}';
    }        
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    $.post('register/isUsernameAvailable', {"username":$(this).val()}, function(data){if(data.username == "found"){alert('username already in use');}}, 'json');
});
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE :**

I"m trying to find out if this is really a PHP issue or jQuery issue.

After it does the POST request it sends this as a parameter:

username testusername

In the response I get this:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  Missing argument 1 for Register::isUsernameAvailable()

Filename: controllers/register.php

Line Number: 118

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined variable: username

Filename: controllers/register.php

Line Number: 120

{"username":"notfound"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$this` can not be overwritten, it is the reference to the object you are in. If you could overwrite it you would lose the object.

In your code you have the line

```
public function isUsernameAvailable($this->input->post('username'))
```

this would cause the functions `isUsernameAvailable` first parameter be name `$this->input->post('username')`. That would cause that `$this` in the scope of the function would be overwritten.

Comment: I'm still confused on what that has to do with my function.

Comment: After reading your actual code (honestly just post code that is necessary) if saw that you are using $this is the name of a function parameter. That can not work.

Comment: Change the function definition to `isUsernameAvaialble( $username)` and pass `$this->input->post('username')` to the function when you call it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php read there which variable names are allowed.

Comment: I didd that Nick but here's what I have for the jquery post. 

$('#username').blur(function(){
        $.post('register/isUsernameAvailable', {"username":$(this).val()}, function(data){if(data.username == "found"){alert('username already in use');}}, 'json');
    });

Comment: Its still saying its missing argument 1 for the isUsernameAvailable function